# Apple raw image reduced quality when uploading to Amazon Photos

Tags: raw, iphone, storage, backup, apple

when backing up my iPhone 14 ProRaw images to Amazon Photos through the iOS app, my 12MP raw DNG photos are only ~1 MB or so. However, on my phone they are closer to 20 MB. After downloading the uplaoded photo from Amazon Photos, the downloaded raw DNG is still only ~1 MB. This doesn't happen to the non-raw photos, i.e. live photos are about ~1 MB on my phone and on Amazon Photos.

By my understanding, Amazon Photos should be saving the full image.

1. Am I losing quality here? Is there any way to check/quantify the quality loss?
2. Anything I can do to prevent this, while still using Amazon Photos?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are sure the files in Amazon photos are really DNG?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yea they are, I just checked again

Comment: Have you check if they are the same resolution, colour depth?

Comment: @RomeoNinov resolution is the same, but how can I check the colour depth?

Comment: XN View MP have function to count unique colours in image.

Comment: @RomeoNinov tried that out. XN View MP thinks that the photo from Amazon Photos has gone through JPEG compression... 24 bits vs 48 bits from the raw image, and the format is JPEG TrueColor v1.1 vs APPLE. I suppose the Amazon Photos iOS app is compressing it before the upload... which is pretty annoying. Thank you so much for this tip!! Wonder if there's a way around that

Comment: In desktop client (Amazon Photos on PC) I have option to backup and option to upload. Do you have them on iPhone client?

Comment: @RomeoNinov from iOS app the only options in "Upload settings" are to "Auto-save" and "Save photos". don't think I can turn it off. I can move my iPhone images to PC first, then upload from Amazon Photos on PC, but it's just an extra step. Anyway thanks for the help here!